# noob: android button

Tags: android, button, android-cursor

I have two button b1 and b2 .If button b1 is pressed then perform a query q1 else if button b2 is pressed then perform an another query q2.

```
if(b1_click)
{
  mCursor=//query
}
else if(b2_click)
{
  mCursor=//query
}
```

Please tell me how can i implement this.How to implement b1_click method or any inbuilt method which tell that button is pressed.I tried

```
Cursor c;
c=//querys

    if(b1.isPressed())
    {
        next.setOnClickListener
        (
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    c=db.getData1(); (getData1 method return cursor)
                }
            }
        );
    } 
   tv.append(c.getString(column_number) (tv=TextView)

   "Same as above for b2"
```

It is saying that cursor (c) should be final 
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend going through some tutorials [Hello Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) and you could also follow the code and samples in [Common Tasks and How to do them in Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html).

If you would read this carefully you would know that is very simple, something like this:

```
public class MyActiviy extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
          super.onCreate(savedInstance);
          setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
          findViewById(R.id.Button1).setOnClickListener(this);
          findViewById(R.id.Button2).setOnClickListener(this);
          //more code...
     }

     public void onClick(View v){
          switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.Button1:
                  //Button1 pressedd...do stuff
                  break;
              case R.id.Button2:
                  //Button2 pressed...do some other stuff
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this type of question but i want mCursor query in            Case R.id.Button1: mCursor.moveToNext();               break;          how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your OnClickListeners as private classes:

```
private class Button1ClickedListener implements OnClickListener {
  public void onClick( View v ) {
    //Do what needs to be done when button 1 is clicked.
  }
}

private class Button2ClickedListener implements OnClickListener {
  public void onClick( View v ) {
    //Do what needs to be done when button 2 is clicked.
  }
}
```

Then you set the onClick-listeners:

```
b1.setOnClickListener( new Button1ClickedListener() );
b2.setOnClickListener( new Button1ClickedListener() );
```

If you need the OnClickListeners to be able to use the cursor, you just need to declare it as a private field in the parent class of the OnClickListeners.